# Can I rotate horizontal and vertical two-finger touchpad scrolling?

Tags: linux-mint, touchpad, xinput

I have a simple script set up to rotate my screen left or right (using xrandr), and it also rotates the touchpad on my laptop. That way, physically rotating the laptop lets the touchpad work intuitively. For example:

```
#rotate left
xrandr --output left
xinput set-prop "$TOUCHPAD"    "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

However, the two-finger scrolling gestures are not rotated properly with this command. For this left rotation, I want to be able to move two fingers left and right to control the vertical scrolling, and likewise up and down for horizontal scrolling.

Is there a property I need to change via xinput to transform the direction of two finger scrolling?

The following is a list of all the current properties for my touchpad:

```
Device 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint':
Device Enabled (138):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (140): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (262): 1
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (263):   2.500000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (264):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (265):    12.500000
Synaptics Edges (290):  614, 3481, 307, 1740
Synaptics Finger (291): 25, 30, 0
Synaptics Tap Time (292):   180
Synaptics Tap Move (293):   201
Synaptics Tap Durations (294):  180, 100, 100
Synaptics ClickPad (295):   0
Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (296):  75
Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (297):    282
Synaptics Two-Finger Width (298):   7
Synaptics Scrolling Distance (299): -91, -91
Synaptics Edge Scrolling (300): 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (301):   1, 1
Synaptics Move Speed (302): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.043687, 0.000000
Synaptics Off (303):    2
Synaptics Locked Drags (304):   0
Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (305):   5000
Synaptics Tap Action (306): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2
Synaptics Click Action (307):   1, 3, 2
Synaptics Circular Scrolling (308): 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (309):    0.100000
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (310): 0
Synaptics Circular Pad (311):   0
Synaptics Palm Detection (312): 0
Synaptics Palm Dimensions (313):    10, 200
Synaptics Coasting Speed (314): 20.000000, 50.000000
Synaptics Pressure Motion (315):    30, 160
Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (316): 1.000000, 1.000000
Synaptics Resolution Detect (317):  1
Synaptics Grab Event Device (318):  0
Synaptics Gestures (319):   1
Synaptics Capabilities (320):   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0
Synaptics Pad Resolution (321): 38, 40
Synaptics Area (322):   0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Noise Cancellation (323): 22, 22
Device Product ID (256):    2, 8
Device Node (257):  "/dev/input/event6"
```